# I added a new preference (Toggle) to my Settings-Watch.Bundle but it will not show in the Watch app

Tags: xcode, apple-watch, preferences, watchos-2, settings.bundle

I added a new preference (Toggle) to my Settings-Watch.Bundle but it will not show in the Watch app... Same on my iPhone device :(

Did I forget to do something?

[image: Settings Bundle Screenshot]

[image: Watch App screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok it seems I needed to add a default value for the Toggle items.
Added them and now it works... Wasted a lot of time on something so obvious
 :(
[image: screenshot of plist.info]